# How To Make Count Of Dynamically Generated Controls In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in a ASP.NET Mvc application, where one clicking an add button, a new set of controls - a dropdownlistfor and textbox is generated from the original. On clicking on submit, data values from some of the controls are passed via WebAPI to the DB while other values are used to generate a PDF using the iTextSharp library.

How can I count the number of dropdownlists and textboxes generated, for a specific feature, e.g the 6 controls you see in the image[image]?

Comment: How do you generate those controls dynamically?

Comment: You could use javascript from what you have shown.

Comment: I used jquery to generate the controls @Win

Comment: Show the code you're using to generate the controls. If you're using javascript, why not just set a variable on the page that is 0 on load, and just increment it each time a control is created?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I count the number of dropdownlists and textboxes generated,

Normally, you could use array, and default model binder could bind it for you. Please make sure controls ids are unique. For example, `id="Unit_0" name="Unit[0]"`

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string[] Stock { get; set; }
    public string[] Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on click/submit (in jQuery)

```
    $('select').each(function(){

    //count your dropdown here

    });

    $('input[type=textbox]').each(function(){

    //count your textbox here

    })
```